# Joomla 2.5 site layout breaks when moved from public_html subfolder to public_html root

Tags: css, .htaccess, joomla, root, public-html

Title says it all. I was like, ok no probs, I'll just make the subfolder disappear with htaccess. And no, it creates the exact same effect, but I'm so new at this that I can't make out what that means.

Layout breaking is like the CSS is falling apart or something. If I run the site in a subfolder I have no problems. I'd just like to make my site look a little more professional by having a clean url so I'm jumping through hoops trying to find out what's wrong but like I said, it's all new to me so debugging is a pain.

My site is www.pienisirkus.fi and since it's a live webshop I can't have it displayed broken so here's a screencap: http://imgur.com/jUaibfL

Everything is exactly the same in the code and everywhere, only the files and folders have been moved into the root folder.

Comment: Backup the system, re-install Joomla in the new directory, import backed up data?

Comment: Hmm... That might work. I'll give it a go and let you know. :)

Comment: Seems that it doesn't work like that. You either backup everything and drop it to a location or you don't. At least I didn't find any options suggesting you could just import some data, unless it's only the database, which doesn't do much good.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the path of your log and tmp folder in Global Configuration and Check "Directory Permissions" in System Information is all writable. it should work

Comment: I've tried and that actually has no effect at all. I wonder why almost every instruction I could find said that it's essential. Permissions are no different in public_html root than its subfolders.

Answer (score 0):

enable the sef plugin, that should take care of relative paths.

And make sure your site is in the root, not just a few .htaccess rules to pretend it's there

Comment: Thanks Riccardo, but the SEF plugin has been enabled the whole time. Trying htaccess was only a try for a workaround that didn't work. At the moment the layout doesn't work while the site is in the root but in a subfolder (no matter the name) everything is just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check mod_rewrite path, in chrome console, target to images and check if is readable. So in this case the problem is in the objects url (images, categories) and other.

Another case would be permissions, but in your screenshot your installation is local? and public_html is your localhost installation?

i recomend to see all images with chrome inspector, disable mod_rewrite and another url SEF and reload the page, check .css with chrome inspector, for example url(image.jpg) and verify if is readable

Thats all can i help you with my experience in joomla, i wait help you.